# Running multiple jekyll app simultaneously

Tags: jekyll, foreman

I was wondering if it is possible to run multiple jekyll app at the same time.
I have installed foreman but it doesn't seem to be able to change the app port when an other one is already running.

At the moment I have to set the jekyll port manually in the Procfile

```
web: jekyll --server 5000
```

Is it in anyway possible to do this automatically?

Answer (score 22):

I think I am a bit late, but here is the answer for those, who have the same problem.
Equally to Ruby on Rails the command `--port 3000` can be used.
So it would look like this:

```
$ jekyll serve --port 8888
```

**Edit:** As mentioned in the documentation you can also simply add the option `port: 8888` in your `_config.yml` file.

#### The new generated file would look like this:

```
name: Your New Jekyll Site
pygments: true
port: 8888
```

*Port 8888 is used here for the example*

#### Further Reading:

- [Jekyll Configuration](http://jekyllrb.com/docs/configuration/#serve-command-options)

---

> These are just a few of the available configuration options. Many configuration options can either be specified as flags on the command line, or alternatively (and more commonly) they can be specified in a _config.yml file at the root of the source directory. Jekyll will automatically use the options from this file when run. For example, if you place the following lines in your `_config.yml` file:
>
> ```
> source:      _source
> destination: _deploy
> ```
>
> Then the following two commands will be equivalent:
>
> ```
> $ jekyll build
> $ jekyll build --source _source --destination _deploy
> ```

So using the command line

```
jekyll serve --port 8888
```

is the equivalent to putting `port: 8888` into your _config.yml.

Comment: Works, but is not really something new. as the comments in the previous answer indicates, the asker wants some kind of auto-detection to use an unused port.

Comment: This should be jekyll serve --port 8888, not --p

Answer (score 1):

Sure.  As your question already suggests, just run the different instances on different server ports (using 5000 instead of the default 4000).  Remember that you can specify the server (and all [other command-line options](https://github.com/mojombo/jekyll/wiki/Configuration)) in the `_config.yml` file if you don't want to specify it in the run command.  Please clarify if I've misunderstood the question.

Comment: no that's correct :). I'm just looking for a way to have the port auto detect if possible. Just so that i don't forget which one are already in use when I switch project. I've set up the port file in my Procfile so far.

Comment: e.g. ideally it would detect that a Jekyll site is running on 4000, and therefore generate one on 5000?  Not sure quite how to do that, but it would probably be easiest to write a Rakefile or bash script that makes the check first (e.g. ping by curl maybe?) and then calls Jekyll with the server number?